# which system call is occured in linux when removing empty directory

Tags: linux, directory, rm

I search few answers regarding this problem but It doesn't work well. many of you told __NR_rmdir, and __NR_unlink. But when I really trace or hooking these system call, It doesn't work properly. 
unlink called only removing files, and rmdir called when use command 'rmdir' in shell or remove() in c code.

What I really want to know is when I command 'rm -r directoryName' in shell, which system call are occured?
I hooked rmdir and unlink system call, but both doesn't detected when 'rm -r empty_directory' even directory is removed!

please give me some advice.

Comment: Can you elaborate more what you are trying to do? Unlink and rmdir both are called when rm -r is used. If directory is empty, then only rmdir is called. Otherwise, recursively unlink is called.

Comment: follow the comment from @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams and run strace to see the system calls.  Rmdir was not present in early unix implementations, so both execute almost the same code (rmdir has to atomically remove the `.` and `..` entries all directories have)

Comment: Thx for comments!!
I was quite busy these days for another assingment.... haha but I finally found the reason.

Comment: I found that when I make a file or some dir, the unlink system call is occured, but It doesn't when I command 'rm~' in shell

Comment: So I guess unlink system call is for temporary file which be removed just before store a real file.
And I looked up the other system call list in linux centOS (asm/unistd.h).

Comment: There was '__NR_unlink', '__NR_unlinkat' and '__NR_mq_unlink' system call in <asm/unistd.h>
I tried other system call '__NR_unlinkat' and '__NR_mq_unlink' instead '__NR_unlink' .
Then it worked!! 
When I command 'rm~' in shell, the syscall_table[__NR_unlinkat] is occured!  and hooking also done well!

Comment: My environment is linux centOS-6.5 32bit (i686). Thanks for comments any way @LuisColorado, lgnacio Vazquez-Abrams